Why I cannot concatenate these 2 items?
At inputs = keras.layers.concatenate([decoder_inputs, encoder_state_h], axis=2), it shows

ValueError: A Concatenate layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concatenation axis. Received: input_shape=[(None, 1, 3), (None, 1, 32)]

Here is the full code.
def get_model_attention(latent_dim):
    # Luong Attention
    # https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.04025

    input_train = keras.layers.Input(shape=(50, 40, 1))

    conv_first1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (1, 2), strides=(1, 2))(input_train)
    conv_first1 = keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01)(conv_first1)
    conv_first1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (4, 1), padding='same')(conv_first1)
    conv_first1 = keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01)(conv_first1)
    conv_first1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (4, 1), padding='same')(conv_first1)
    conv_first1 = keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01)(conv_first1)

    conv_first1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (1, 2), strides=(1, 2))(conv_first1)
    conv_first1 = keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01)(conv_first1)
    conv_first1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (4, 1), padding='same')(conv_first1)
    conv_first1 = keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01)(conv_first1)
    conv_first1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (4, 1), padding='same')(conv_first1)
    conv_first1 = keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01)(conv_first1)

    conv_first1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (1, 10))(conv_first1)
    conv_first1 = keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01)(conv_first1)
    conv_first1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (4, 1), padding='same')(conv_first1)
    conv_first1 = keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01)(conv_first1)
    conv_first1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (4, 1), padding='same')(conv_first1)
    conv_first1 = keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01)(conv_first1)

    # build the inception module
    convsecond_1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (1, 1), padding='same')(conv_first1)
    convsecond_1 = keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01)(convsecond_1)
    convsecond_1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 1), padding='same')(convsecond_1)
    convsecond_1 = keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01)(convsecond_1)

    convsecond_2 = keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (1, 1), padding='same')(conv_first1)
    convsecond_2 = keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01)(convsecond_2)
    convsecond_2 = keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (5, 1), padding='same')(convsecond_2)
    convsecond_2 = keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01)(convsecond_2)

    convsecond_3 = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((3, 1), strides=(1, 1), padding='same')(conv_first1)
    convsecond_3 = keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (1, 1), padding='same')(convsecond_3)
    convsecond_3 = keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.01)(convsecond_3)

    convsecond_output = keras.layers.concatenate([convsecond_1, convsecond_2, convsecond_3], axis=3)
    conv_reshape = keras.layers.Reshape((int(convsecond_output.shape[1]), int(convsecond_output.shape[3])))(
        convsecond_output)

    # seq2seq
    encoder_inputs = conv_reshape
    encoder = keras.layers.LSTM(latent_dim, return_state=True, return_sequences=True)
    encoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = encoder(encoder_inputs)
    states = [state_h, state_c]

    # Set up the decoder, which will only process one timestep at a time.
    decoder_inputs = keras.layers.Input(shape=(1, 3))
    decoder_lstm = keras.layers.LSTM(latent_dim, return_sequences=True, return_state=True)
    decoder_dense = keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax', name='output_layer')

    all_outputs = []
    all_attention = []

    encoder_state_h = keras.layers.Reshape((1, int(state_h.shape[1])))(state_h)
    inputs = keras.layers.concatenate([decoder_inputs, encoder_state_h], axis=2)

    for _ in range(5):
        # h'_t = f(h'_{t-1}, y_{t-1}, c)
        outputs, state_h, state_c = decoder_lstm(inputs, initial_state=states)
        # dot
        attention = keras.layers.dot([outputs, encoder_outputs], axes=2)
        attention = keras.layers.Activation('softmax')(attention)
        # context vector
        context = keras.layers.dot([attention, encoder_outputs], axes=[2, 1])
        context = keras.layers.BatchNormalization(momentum=0.6)(context)

        # y = g(h'_t, c_t)
        decoder_combined_context = keras.layers.concatenate([context, outputs])
        outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_combined_context)
        all_outputs.append(outputs)
        all_attention.append(attention)

        inputs = keras.layers.concatenate([outputs, context], axis=2)
        states = [state_h, state_c]

    # Concatenate all predictions
    decoder_outputs = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: K.concatenate(x, axis=1), name='outputs')(all_outputs)
    decoder_attention = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: K.concatenate(x, axis=1), name='attentions')(all_attention)

    # Define and compile model as previously
    model = keras.models.Model([input_train, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
    return model

I expect it can be concatenated to form (None,1,35)
